# How do I amend Magento 2 'Bundle' products layout in PDF Invoices?

Tags: magento2, invoice-pdf

I've successfully amended my Magento 2 PDF invoices, changing the styling, adding a footer etc. I've managed to move the 'Qty' so that it's first in the item list, as below:

[image: Invoice]

However, I can't seem to find out how to amend the items if a bundle product is added:

[image: Invoice]

I would like to move the 'Qty' first, and add the individual bundled items SKUs (in the correct place - the example above's SKU (QUARTERLY) is still in the original position of the default invoice).

I've overridden the following files, but don't seem to be able to find / change the bundle product options.

`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`
`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice.php`